# Async web service call in custom list adapter

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem when calling web service asynchronously in Monodroid. The call seems to work correctly, but the application crashes everytime when I process the response. Program behaves differently when I run it in emulator and when I run it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S w 2.2.1 FROYO.XWJS8). I am thinking of creting the Threads by myself, but don't know if it solves the problem. The same code works fine when used in Windows Phone 7 application.

The code for Async method call is (note: in reality ShowMessage calls write to Android.Util.Log.Debug)

```
private void callws(string _input)
{
     MessageBox.GetInstance().ShowMessage("Search async started, input: " + _input); 
     m_waitingrequest = new RequestStatus() { Waiting = true, NewestInput = _input, OriginalInput = _input };
     connectormobile.UserInformation ui = new connectormobile.UserInformation() 
        { UserName = m_appsettings.GetValue<string>(AppSettings.WS_USERNAME_NAME), Password = m_appsettings.GetValue<string>(AppSettings.WS_PASSWORD_NAME) };
     MessageBox.GetInstance().ShowMessage("Username: " + ui.UserName + " Password: " + ui.Password);
     m_client.SearchAsync(ui, _input);
     MessageBox.GetInstance().ShowMessage("After search async call, input: " + _input);
}
```

Search Async result function starts with:

```
void m_client_SearchCompleted(object sender, connectormobile.SearchCompletedEventArgs e)
{
             MessageBox.GetInstance().ShowMessage("Search async completed");
            SearchCache.CacheElement element = new SearchCache.CacheElement();
            element.SearchCriteria = m_waitingrequest.OriginalInput;
            element.PartialResponse = e.Result.PartialResponse;

            if (e.Result.CompanyNameInfoArray == null)
                element.Rows = new List<connectormobile.CompanyNameInfo>();
            else
                element.Rows = e.Result.CompanyNameInfoArray.ToList();
            MessageBox.GetInstance().ShowMessage("Search async returned, partial response: " + e.Result.PartialResponse
                + " row count: " + element.Rows.Count + " return value: " + e.Result.ReturnValue.ErrorDescriptionFi);
}
```

This is where the program behaves differently. In emulator the code never reaches the first line of SearchCompleted. But in my phone the SearchCompleted function seems goes through (at least all my debug lines are in trace), but after that the user interface freezes. (and after minute it says process not responding)

Comment: I think we'll need a complete test case to further diagnose this. Could you file a bug via http://mono-android.net/Support with a complete, self-contained test app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to modify the UI from the background thread instead of the UI thread.  Use RunOnUIThread () to do your UI logic on the correct thread:

http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Writing_Responsive_Applications

Comment: Did not help. The only thing I'm doing to user interface is call Adapters m_context.RunOnUiThread(() => this.NotifyDataSetChanged());